# Sorting on insertion with a comparing function

Tags: c#, sorting, insert, comparison

I'm trying to sort data of a type T in a container by two of T's properties. It's potentially a lot of data, so I would much rather have the sorting happen on insertion. I've looked into both `List` and `SortedList`, but both don't quite provide the functionality I need.

Does C# provide a container that allows both sorting on insertion and sorting my a comparison function? I would like to avoid post insertion sorting like `List.Sort`, and avoid the overhead of using the data as both key and value for `SortedList`.

Comment: There is an `IComparer` interface that may help with sorting functions. Each element could use your custom comparer object to sort by any combination of element properties. It may be necessary to implement `IList<T>` for a custom sorting container.

Comment: Have a look in to this post...probably it will answer your question: http://devlicio.us/blogs/marcin_hoppe/archive/2007/05/15/how-to-keep-list-t-sorted.aspx

Comment: This seems to be a more algorithmic than a datastructure problem. Do you have a defined endpoint, when all data is inserted in your list? Do you need the data while more data get inserted? Do you need multiple identical values in this list? What do you call "lot of data"?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using .NET 4, you could use [`SortedSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) with a custom `IComparer<T>`. The downside is that it won't allow you to have multiple equal elements. Do you need that?

It's not clear to me *why* you want sorting on insertion just because you've got a lot of data though. Do you need it to be sorted before you've finished inserting? If not, I'd expect a single sort at the end (via `List.Sort`) to be as efficient as an as-you-go sort.

Comment: Do I hear you saying this sounds like an XY Problem, @JonSkeet?

Comment: Well sort of. I wouldn't go quite that far, but it's at least worth further consideration.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the same sorting order all the time, you can use `SortedList<K,V>` or `SortedDictionary<K,V>` and pass a `IComparer<K>` to the constructor.

If you need different sorting orders on the same container, you can use a `List<T>` and pass a `IComparer<T>` to the `Sort` method.

Since you are probably storing reference types, I would not worry too much about using the items as key as well as values. You are just storing the references.

Another option would be to implement your own binary-tree structure.

Comment: With the given information, your answer should solve the problem.